# Core Data object graph design decision

Tags: iphone, ios, database, core-data

I am designing an app which tracks data on `Game` objects. Each `Game` has a `name`, a `date` and other attributes. The problem I am having arises because I want the user to be able to add more names (for example) to pick from in the application. (in this case from a UITableView). So the user is presented with a list of names to choose from, and if the one they want is not in the list, they can add one to the list.

My solution is that I currently have a second entity called `GameName` so that I can show the user a list of those game names to pick from when they are adding a new `Game`. I just call an `NSFetchRequest` on all the `GameName` objects and display them in the `UITableView`. There doesn't have to be a `Game` object created yet to do this.

My dilemma is that I want to know if this is a good practice. It seems that if I do it this way, I will end up having a lot of entities with just one attribute, for the sake of allowing the user to pick from and add to a customizable list.

I hope this makes sense. I can clarify anything upon request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is fine, and is commonly used in database design. The entity you want to add is called a "domain table" in databases. See [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_domain), in particular this paragraph:

> In a normalized data model, the reference domain is typically specified in a reference table. Following the previous example, a Gender reference table would have exactly two records, one per allowed value—excluding NULL. Reference tables are formally related to other tables in a database by the use of foreign keys.

Of course, you probably want to have an optional relationship between the `GameName` and `Game` entities.

Comment: Thanks so much for the link and advice. I feel much better about what I'm doing now.